# getopt passing parameter without quotes

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This is the bash script i wrote:

```
if ! options=$(/usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt/bin/getopt -o hro: -l help,reuse,outdir: -- "$@")
then
    # something went wrong, getopt will put out an error message for us
    exit 1
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
    -r|--reuse) cmd_options=--reuse-last-results ;;
    -h|--help) usage;;
    -o|--outdir) out_dir=$2; shift;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (-*) echo "$0: error - unrecognized option $1" 1>&2; exit 1;;
    (*) break;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

The problem is I get the value of out_dir with quotes.
for example:

```
test.sh --outdir ./here -r
```

`echo $outdir` comes out to be `'./here'`. Please suggest how to remove quotes.

Comment: Instead of `$1` you may use `${1//'/}`. This expands the parameter `$1` with the single quotes removed.

Comment: With `getopt from util-linux 2.20.1` and `bash version 4.2.37(1)-release`, the problem doesn't appear.